# What is the purpose of NilClass, TrueClass, and FalseClass

Tags: ruby, language-design, null

`NilClass`, `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` having one instance each, namely `nil`, `true` and `false`, which are constants, what is the purpose of having these classes? Why cannot they be instances of the `Object` class, and all the relevant methods be simply defined as singleton methods on `nil`, `true` and `false`? A related question is, why are these not defined as constants?

Comment: Good question, it's like this in Python too, so there must be some good reason behind it.

Comment: Constants in ruby are not really constant, http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/constants.html

Comment: A question to you. What would be the benefit of *NOT* having separate classes for each of these values? Using singleton methods is rarely the simplest solution and adds unneeded complexity IMO.

Comment: @diedthreetimes Not having a separate class will bring less things to the langauge, making it simpler. Why do you think singleton methods adds complexity?

Comment: @sawa Less things does not always mean less complexity. Remember everything is an object. So technically, you could use your approach for all objects. Although creating new instances may take a little extra work. The class keyword is a very short, concise abstraction, that there is little reason to not use in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It keeps with the idea that "everything is an object" and "objects are specialized by the classes they are instances of".

`nil`, `true`, and `false` are all objects (and are thus instantiations of a class with methods). The imposition that they are 1) the sole inhabitants of the respective type and are 2) immutable objects *allows for implementation optimizations* -- and really, isn't *one* `nil` enough?

A helpful error message without specialization for the values: `x.class` "just works".

```
> > nil.foo
> => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass>
```

I am glad it said `NilClass` :-)

This class-instance approach also makes re-opening `NilClass` -- for better or worse -- as easy and consistent with how it might be done for other types.

At least as of Ruby 1.9.2 it is not possible to re-assign `true`, `false` or `nil` (Python 2.x allowed re-assignment of True/False, but does not in Python 3.x). Note that because `true/false/nil` are *not* constants they can be optimized into the AST -- or whatever the implementation uses -- as "literal values" without a constant look-up.

```
> > VERSION
> => "1.9.2"
> > true = false­
> => #<SyntaxError: Can't change the value of true>
> > [].each {|tru­e|}
> => #<SyntaxError: Can't change the value of true>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Of course these are objects, and have to belong to some class. I am asking why they cannot be instances of the `Object` class. I get your second part of the answer regarding constant. That clears me with that point.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby takes the approach of "just take an object and add some singleton methods to it" some of the time:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\a.grimm>irb
irb(main):001:0> self.methods - Object.new.methods
```

gives

> [:public, :private, :include, :context, :conf, :irb_quit, :exit,
>   :quit, :irb_print_working_workspace, :irb_cwws, :irb_pwws, :cwws,
>   :pwws, :irb_current_working_binding, :irb_print_working_binding,
>   :irb_cwb, :irb_pwb, :irb_chws, :irb_cws, :chws, :cws,
>   :irb_change_binding, :irb_cb, :cb, :workspaces, :irb_bindings,
>   :bindings, :irb_pushws, :pushws, :irb_push_binding, :irb_pushb,
>   :pushb, :irb_popws, :popws, :irb_pop_binding, :irb_popb, :popb,
>   :source, :jobs, :fg, :kill, :help, :irb_exit, :irb_context,
>   :install_alias_method, :irb_current_working_workspace,
>   :irb_change_workspace, :irb_workspaces, :irb_push_workspace,
>   :irb_pop_workspace, :irb_load, :irb_require, :irb_source, :irb,
>   :irb_jobs, :irb_fg, :irb_kill, :irb_help]

I don't know why they don't do this approach with `true`, `false` or `nil`. Maybe because people need to understand these objects (as per pst's answer), whereas people don't need to understand the "main" (?) object.

Comment: The main object seems like a special case to me. Most programs never reference even reference it once.